# 'bitbake' detect changes but 'make' do nothing

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, yocto, bitbake

I'm using yocto dunfell (3.1).

I built recipe for my appication, where 'bitbake' calls 'do_compile' which calls 'oe_runmake' which runs 'make'.
CFLAGS are defined at the recipe, and passed by 'oe_runmake' internally to 'make'.
usually, this process runs OK.

the problem arise when:

1. I change only the CFLAGS at the recipe. no any change at sources.
2. 'bitbake' detects the change, runs 'do_compile', which runs 'oe_runmake' which runs 'make'.
3. 'make' does not detect any change at sources, and do nothing.

during development cycle, I can run 'make clean' manually before 'bitbake', forcing 'make' to compile all sources with the new CFLAGS. However, this process shall run at build server, who automatically pulls new revisions from git and runs 'bitbake'.

any idea?

Comment: make only cares about changes to files that are listed as prerequisites in the recipe.  It doesn't care about changes in the text of the recipe itself (for example, changes to the CFLAGS variable value).  What would it compare these values to?  make doesn't have any database of previous runs, or what the values of these flags were before, that it can tell something has changed.

Comment: One thing people sometimes do is list the Makefile itself, or a file that contains the variable settings, as prerequisites of the relevant targets.  Then any time the makefile is changed, or the config variables are changed, that file will be newer than the targets and they will be rebuilt.

Answer (score 0):

If `bitbake -c compile <recipe>` does not take in account change you make try doing `bitbake -c clean <recipe> && bitbake recipe` or, if changes are in recipe only, eg. `CFLAGS:append = "...` you can wipe out whole recipe's workspace using `bitbake -c cleanall <recipe>`.

Answer (score 0):

As MadScientist commented, I added the recipe file to the prerequisites of the relevant targets at the makefile. this solved the problem.
thanks